# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: xxxx already defined

Tags: php, wcf, web-services

I am trying to read in this .NET WCF Basic http binding web service:
http://videoconferencingbookingsystem.com/BasicInfo/WhyGoService.svc?wsdl

My calling script is as follows:

```
define('RESPONSE_TIMEOUT', 600);
set_time_limit(RESPONSE_TIMEOUT+30);

header('Content-Type: text/plain');


$options = array(
   'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
   'trace' => 1,
   'connection_timeout' => 30,
   'login' => 'xxxxxxx',
   'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
   'trace' => 1
   );

$client = new SoapClient('http://videoconferencingbookingsystem.com/BasicInfo/WhyGoService.svc?wsdl', $options);
```

...and I'm getting this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL:  'IWhygoService_getBasicInformation_InputMessage' already defined

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: It seems the error comes from the php side which I can't help with. Just to verify - if you put fiddler does the client send anything to the server and get any kind of response?

Comment: See if this can be of any help, it is a question very similar to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906871/fatal-error-uncaught-soapfault-exception-wsdl

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing a debug trace I couldnt be much help, but looking quickly at the code

Do you need trace twice in the options? Shouldnt it be true/false anyway rather than the bit representation?

If you have a debugger which returns trace it'd help :)

Answer (score -2):

I had an exact similar problem a month ago when changing some code into a WCF service, and then trying to have a different application use the service.. A program called SoapUI helped me pin-point my problem in like 2 minutes.

http://soapui.org/

It's free too.